# How to concat unicode string with numbers?

Tags: c#, unicode

How can I concat unicode string with numbers?
in my code

```
label1.Text = String.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4}", "111", "هتل", "222", "اقامت", "333");
```

I want a result like this:

[image]

But result is :

```
111 هتل 222 اقامت 333
```

Comment: Can you explain *why* you expected the result you wanted?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Cause he typed the values exactly the way you see in the picture. But .Net gets messy merging those stuffs with numbers

Comment: There must be something I'm not getting here. The code says that first he wants `111`, then he wants `333`, then a string containing foreign (to me) unicode characters, but somehow he wants a completely different ordering? Again, why would you expect this code to behave like that? To me the actual result is perfectly sane and expected. Why do you expect something other than I do?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen If you try to put that *foreign* characters next to numbers, you'll get it. I know what OP sys cause i speak the same language as he does, and I sometimes have the same unicode issues.

Comment: But the *string concatenation* works just fine, it's *the label* that is the problem.

Comment: Basically, `string.Format` does exactly what it is documented to do, put all the parts into one string in the specified order. That you want the *label* to display them in a different order because of right-to-left ordering or something like that is not a problem with the *string concatenation*.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your item index orders like;

```
label1.Text = String.Format("{0} {2} {3} {4} {1}", "111", "هتل", "222", "اقامت", "333");
```

Also I would suggest to change your objects orders as well but I couldn't change their orders in some unicode weirdness in answer window on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Use linebreaks to prevent weird actions from .net. Most editors do messy stuffs when merging right-to-left characters with numbers.

```
label1.Text = String.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4}", "111",
"اقامت",
"222",
"هتل",
"333");
```